# URLFetchApp.fetch() gets stuck on some urls

Tags: google-apps-script, cookies, urlfetch

I'm looping through a spreadsheet with a list of URLs to get the response code so my team can be aware of 404s. Everything works fine, except some urls don't return anything and cause my loop to get stuck.

Someone suggested it could be a cookie issue on those urls, but I'm not sure how I would handle that if it is indeed the case.

As an alternative, is there a way to skip over urls that don't return anything after a few seconds? I know URLFetchApp doesn't have a timeout option. Any Javascript hacks for this situation?

I'm running this function from my range loop:

```
function getStatusCode(url) {
     var options = {
       'muteHttpExceptions': true,
       'followRedirects': false
     }
     var url_trimmed = url.trim(); // to remove any possible spaces
     var response = URLFetchApp.fetch(url_trimmed, options);
     return response.getResponseCode();
}
```

And here is my loop that calls getStatusCode(). I am looping through 10 rows at a time and then setting the status code before resetting and moving on to the next set of 10.

```
var finalOutput = [];
var counter = 0; // Just for logging purposes
var code = '';
var startRange = 2;
for (c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
     var range = sheet.getRange(startRange,3,10,2);
     var urls = range.getValues();
     for (u = 0; u < urls.length; u++) {
       code = getStatusCode(urls[u][0]);
       finalOutput.push(urls[u][0],code); 
       counter++;
     } 
}
range.setValues(finalOutput);
counter = 0;
startRange += 10; // Increment range to the next 10 rows
finalOutput = []; // Reset the array
```

As requested, here are a couple of urls that cause the loop to hang:

https://www.npr.org/programs/ted-radio-hour/694278104/bias-and-perception

https://www.mckinsey.com/business-functions/strategy-and-corporate-finance/our-insights/how-to-master-the-seven-step-problem-solving-process?cid=other-eml-ttn-mip-mck&hlkid=95d3bf6d8de34e0d92d75ccfa877f204&hctky=2563923&hdpid=7d90901a-d6e3-4c0d-8a7c-609a2217ae8c

Links to npr.org always seem to cause the problem.

Comment: Please add some problematic url examples so other might reproduce the problem.

Comment: As there is no loop in the script you’ve shown, include the looping portion of code.

Comment: Added in a couple example urls and the loop code.